Streamlit st.session_state keys, for clicked images, show old values on re-runs after they are set to None
I'm trying to create an web application using python streamlit, that displays a grid of images.
User's can then click an image, perform an operation, and update the clicked image.
The problem I'm facing is that streamlit's st.session_state seems to bring back values for clicked images, even when I try to wipe them.
Streamlit doesn't have a solution to handle images clicks, so i used either streamlit_image_coordinates and st-click-detector. Both components reproduce this problem.
One solution for this problem is to set a key that is unique for each image, or every re-run. I used time.time() for this.
It's not a great solution however, since it adds a significant load time on the application. From my understanding, streamlit does less processing on widgets (it this case, an image) for which their st.session_state.key did not change.
Here is a simple code, which I hope shows this problem:
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_image_coordinates import streamlit_image_coordinates as st_ic

st.subheader("START")
st.write(st.session_state)

grid = [[0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 0]]
image_default = "data/sprites/Empty_Module.png"
col_states, col_grid = st.columns([2,2], gap="small")

# Store click in session_state.click
for k, v in st.session_state.items():
    if k.startswith(("0_", "1_", "2_")) and v:
        st.session_state.click = k
        break


col_states.subheader("BEFORE SANITIZATION")
col_states.write(st.session_state)

# Set states for image coords to None
for k, v in st.session_state.items():
    if k.startswith(("0_", "1_", "2_")) and v:
        st.session_state[k] = None

col_states.subheader("AFTER SANITIZATION")
col_states.write(st.session_state)

# Main loop to generate grid layout
with col_grid:
    for row_idx, row in enumerate(grid):
        cols = st.columns(len(row), gap="small")
        for cell_idx, cell in enumerate(cols):
            if row[cell_idx] != 0:
                with cell:
                    # Image coords are stored with key int_int in session_state
                    cell_key = f"{row_idx}_{cell_idx}"

                    st_ic(source=image_default,
                          key=cell_key,
                          use_column_width=True)

col_states.subheader("AFTER LOOP")
col_states.write(st.session_state)


So i found a solution when using st-click-detector. This component can display a base64 image and adds a key:value to st.session_state that contains the key used for the component (cell_key in above code) and the value of the html(css?) image.
I used time.time() for the value and just select the key with the latest time, as my clicked image.
For streamlit_image_coordinates however, I had to modify the main.js file for that package and a const unixTime = Date.now();.
return is now sendValue({x: offsetX, y: offsetY, width: img.width, height: img.height, unix_time: unixTime});
